# Using jquery variable in Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a table in which there are input buttons with attribute data. I want to read the value of this attribute and pass it on to razor's routeurl.

My jquery function:

```
$('#table').on("click", "input.myClass", function () {
    var abc = $(this).attr('data');
    var myroute = @Url.RouteUrl("Routename", abc)-- > It says abc not defined
        //use myroute  
});
```

Comment: Do you know what values are in the data attributes when the page is rendered?  If so it might make more sense to build out your URL on the server-side.

Comment: what i have experience you can't use js variable in razor but vica vera is possible

Answer (score 0):

what i have experience you can't use js variable in razor but vica vera is possible.

so You have to achieve it by doing something like this:

```
var myroute = '@Url.RouteUrl("Routename")';

myroute = myroute +"/"+ abc;
```

Suppose route rendered by RouteUrlHelper is:

```
var myroute =   '/Home/About';
var abc = 1;
```

concatenate value with it:

```
 myroute = myroute +"/"+ abc;// --->  /Home/About/1
```

Comment: For my requirement "Routename" in your code has to come from attribute of an html element. How do I read this in Razor? Can I read an attribute in razor by some way?

Comment: html element attribute you mean?

Comment: you just need to replace in your code with these two lines in your click event

Answer (score 0):

Another method I use is this one:

```
var myroute = "@Url.RouteUrl("Routename","-abc")";
myroute = myroute.replace("-abc", abc);
```

1. You create your url o route with a dummy text parameter with a "-" (in your case "-abc")
2. Then you replace where is "-abc" with your actual abc javascript variable
3. You can use it with the value now available.